# How does Shiro get into the Deadman Wonderland?

Tags: deadman-wonderland

We know that Deadman Wonderland is a brutal prison for convicted criminals.

And at various points in the show, it is revealed how each of the main characters ended up there. (what crime they were convicted of)

But how did Shiro get there? Is it ever revealed what Shiro did to end up in that prison?

[image][image]

We know that Shiro was Ganta's childhood friend. So that means that she started off outside in the normal world. But are there any clues to what brought her into Deadman Wonderland?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even though Shiro and Ganta were childhood friends,

> Shiro was used in experiments by the director (Hagire Rinichiro) and Ganta's mother. This was all before Deadman Wonderland was created, and when the director founded it, he created a special room for Shiro. Shiro wasn't imprisoned there, but lived there so that the experiments to create the "Wretched Egg" (Shiro's other personality) can continue, thus she was brought there by the director when Deadman Wonderland was created.

This was mentioned briefly in the [Deadman Wonderland wiki](http://deadmanwonderland.wikia.com/wiki/Shiro#History).

Comment: That's interesting. I don't think that was ever revealed in the Anime. (Or if it was, it wasn't obvious...)

Comment: @Mysticial I don't think it was either, there was that bit where the director revealed what his real plans were and his relation to Shiro, but never mentioned that he brought Shiro to Deadman Wonderland.

Comment: That's because she was never *bought into* the facility.

Answer (score 7):

Deadman Wonderland was originally the medical center in the flashbacks, but when it was destroyed by the [Great Tokyo Earthquake](http://deadmanwonderland.wikia.com/wiki/Great_Tokyo_Earthquake), the prison was built over it.

> Deadman Wonderland was built specifically to contain Shiro's second, more sinister personality, the [Wretched Egg](http://deadmanwonderland.wikia.com/wiki/Wretched_Egg), aka the original Deadman, the Red Man. At the heart of the facility is the [Mother Goose System](http://deadmanwonderland.wikia.com/wiki/Mother_Goose_System) which was designed to transmit a lullaby that suppresses the Wretched Egg. This way you could say the heart of the facility exists to contain her, and that's why she's there.

Answer (score 2):

Deadman Wonderland was built on ground zero of the Great Tokyo earthquake, also being the place where Shiro and Ganta lived during their childhood, to suppress poor Shiro with speakers, made partly of her own flesh and blood, aka the Mother Goose System. Shiro is the original sin, the original deadman, which Ganta was supposed to be.

I honestly doubt there will ever be any more shown in the anime, since key characters have been missing, but let's hope for a continuation.

Answer (score 0):

Shiro was adopted by Hagire (the man who was the "boss" of the National Medical Center later Deadman Wonderland (after the earthquake). She was used as an experiment subject, so they did a lot of painful experiments on her. Later they build D.W. with its main goal to keep Shiro there (the Red man) and to collect every branch of sin. So with that Hagire can get rid of the MotherGoose system and can become like Shiro.